# Powershell - Split Tab delimited CSV by string & convert to HTML

Tags: powershell

I am able to export out a HTML table file from the tab delimited CSV using my below code. However, I'm trying to now export out separate HTML's based on the sort column below; any help with the below code would be appreciated!

Powershell Code

```
    $Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
"@

Import-Csv -delimiter "`t" -Path .\test.txt  | Select DATE,Recipeint,To,BODY,Sort| ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header| Out-File .\test.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following if you want multiple HTML tables in one file:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.txt -Delimiter "`t" |
    Sort-Object {[int]$_.Sort} | Group-Object -Property Sort | Foreach {
        $_.Group | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header } | Out-File .\test.html
```

If you want to output the split data into multiple files, you can do the following:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.txt -Delimiter "`t" |
    Sort-Object {[int]$_.Sort} | Group-Object -Property Sort | Foreach {
        $OutFile = ".\test{0}.html" -f $_.Group.Sort
        $_.Group | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header | Out-File $OutFile
    }
```

**Explanation:**

[Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) groups objects together based on a property value. If we group on property `Sort`, it will return a number of groups that match the number of different `Sort` values.

For [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7), the `Sort` property is being cast to `[int]` first to make sorting numeric.

Comment: That is perfect, last thing how do I sort the HTML file output by the date so that each conversation flows normally. Im using the multiple file code you provided.

Comment: In `Sort-Object`, you can use `-Property {[int]$_.Sort,[datetime]$_.Date}`. `-Property` accepts an array of properties and the precedence is from left to right.